# Sumar en java script

Tags: javascript

quisiera crear una función suma en la que al llamar a dicha función guarda el valor del input y el operador (suma) en variables globales, el id "igual" y llama a la función que mostrará el resultado calculado en el input.
Disculpad, pero me inicio ahora en javascript y NO ENTIENDO NADA.
Quisiera llegar a entender el funcionamiento de algo, que creo, es tan básico como éste ejercicio.
De nuevo, disculpad las molestias.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Entrega P2P: Calculadora</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function vaciar() {
        document.getElementById("n1").value = "";
      }

     
        let num = document.getElementById("n1");
      var suma = document.getElementById('suma');
      function suma(); {
      let num = resultado.parseFloat;
      operacion = "+";
      vaciar();
  }
 function igual ();{
    document.getElementById("n1") = resultado.textContent +document.getElementById("n1") ;
      resolver();
  }
  function igual(){
  var res = 0;

  switch(operacion){
    case "+":
      res = parseFloat(resultado.textContent) + document.getElementById("n1");
      break;
  }
  }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Número
    <input type="text" id="n1" onclick="vaciar()" />

    <button id="suma" onclick="suma(); ">+</button>
    <button onclick="inverso()">1/x</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Te recomiendo utilizar `let` en lugar de `var` puedes investigar sobre la diferencia entre estas: var let y const [Sentencia LET y VAR](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/let)

2. Tienes 2 funciones con el mismo nombre `function igual()` tienes que corregir esto!
3. Hay una funcion que me esta haciendo ruido, la  `function vaciar()` estas llamando a un elemento el cual ya lo tienes almacenado en la variable `num` ademas la mandas a llamar cuando se presiona el input ¿Que necesidad hay de esto?
4. Hay mas detalles en tu codigo claro esta,
5. Te recomiendo hacer una sola funcion en la cual le pases como parametro el elemento y el operador

   ```
   function operacion(elemento, operador){

   }
   ```
6. Al elemento le extraes su value ya que es un `input` y podrias hacer lo del `switch` y dependiendo del operador que recibas es la operacion que realizas
7. Intentalo y muestras tus avances.